# That hid Satoshi Nakamoto in your code

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, cryptography

I tried to find in the code puzzles from Satoshi Nakamoto and I may have found them.
How do you think the meaning of these symbols?

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L110-L113

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation

magic values

d9b4bef9 f9beb4d9

bed9b4f9 b4d9bef9

d9f9beb4 d9f9b4be

Base64 online decoder
http://base64.ru/

/-------------------------------------

罿֞罭罯罯渷枯罭罭罷ָ睷枷֞潭罿ָ罭罷

罀 罷 渀 港 罿֞ 渷 枀 枭 罭 罿ָ

/-------------------------------------

You can try iterating combinations of those numbers, you get Chinese or Korean letter
I don't know what these letters mean. But one who knows the Chinese language, can touch the letters and create words

I'd like to read the letter, and I will be glad if someone will try to solve it :)

Satoshi Nakamoto was involved in cryptography, and I believe that as a true lover of cryptography it is encrypted message for fans to guess the puzzle as we are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to find in the code puzzles from Satoshi Nakamoto and I may have found them.

I don't think you have. I obviously don't know for sure, but let me explain why I think these numbers are (1) not a secret message and (2) why this does not matter.

> How do you think the meaning of these symbols?
>   https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L110-L113

These 4 bytes are known as the network magic, and are common practice in binary formats and protocols, as a means for making sure you're talking to a peer that talks the same protocol.

The original code by Bitcoin's creator even had a comment that explains the choice of these values:

`// The message start string is designed to be unlikely to occur in normal data.
// The characters are rarely used upper ascii, not valid as UTF-8, and produce
// a large 4-byte int at any alignment.
static const char pchMessageStart[4] = { 0xf9, 0xbe, 0xb4, 0xd9 };`

So they're just 4 arbitrary bytes chosen in such a way that they're unlikely to occur in text or as an encoding of common integers in typical protocols.

> Satoshi Nakamoto was involved in cryptography, and I believe that as a true lover of cryptography it is encrypted message for fans to guess the puzzle as we are.

I think 4 bytes is way too little to encode any meaningful message.

Furthermore, it does not matter. While Bitcoin's creator came up with all the right pieces to make a distributed digital currency work in practice, its largest innovation compared to previous attempts is the lack of trusted parties. No need to trust a central bank, or trust the people you're transacting with, or trust **who came up with the idea**.

I'm sure you can come up with many patterns that fit whatever 4 bytes, if you really want to. That doesn't mean there is a meaning.

Comment: Maybe you're right, I don't deny your option, but I would like to know all combinations of phrases of these 4 bytes